# Composite is to component as Aggregate is to __?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a noun for something that is aggregational to an aggregate? There are many permutations of the word 'aggregate' yet as far as I can tell none of them are similar to 'component', despite the similarities between composition and aggregation.

Comment: additives, elements, constituents...

Comment: I was hoping for a derivative of the root word, but this does answer the question. Thank you

Comment: Try *fragment*.

Comment: Ironically the noun *aggregate* can apply to both the combination of ingredients that is concrete and the rock-like elements often added to cement and other components to make concrete. Similarly *admixture*.

Comment: The word-or-is-it 'aggregand' has been used in the computing field. [[Datalog Reloaded: First International Workshop, Datalog 2010, Oxford, UK ...
edited by Oege de Moo](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JTeqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=aggregand&source=bl&ots=bOU1i5MIy_&sig=WmvLJCD8MtPP6zNUbvzOiJkAyxM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdo-bfw7bSAhUrAsAKHYO8AMsQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=aggregand&f=false)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is actually the reason I am searching for such a word funnily enough. I may end up using 'aggregand' despite it not appearing in many (if any) dictionaries; I think its existing usage in the computing field validates my use of the word.

Comment: It's so rare that I'd define it and give an example of its being used before trying to use it as an acceptable word.

Comment: In this case, Composite is to component as Aggregate is to component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be "no". I suppose the candidate word would be "aggregant"[1], which doesn't exist.

Maybe the difference with "composite" is that components of a system are "put together" (as in the Latin etymology) in a specific way, and so there is a need to talk about them in relationship to each other and to the whole they make up. Whereas an aggregate has always been a more loosely-based grouping of just stuff that may or may not have specific relationships to each other (going back to the Latin etymology which seems to be "to flock"); it may simply be that there's never been a big need to refer to the elements of an aggregate as specifically belonging to an aggregate, as opposed to using general words for subsets of things or words that refer to those individual items specifically. Like element, component, subset, item, unit...

ETA-

[1] "aggregand" from Edwin Ashworth's comment does sound better.

Comment: My first instinct was to use 'aggregant' as well, only to find it made a synonym of 'aggregator' by the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aggregant). I've decided to use 'aggregand', which was suggested by Edwin Ashworth's comment. Thank you all for your help!